# Problemas em gerar uma tabela

Tags: php, sql, tabela-html

Estou tendo muita dificuldade em fazer uma tabela. Alguém conseguiria fazer uma tabela que mostre os horários que um funcionário fez durante o mês?  a ideia seria mostrar as batidas dos funcionários durante o mês.

No meu banco teria a tabela que guardaria essas batidas dos funcionários:

---

**marcacoes**
**batida_id** (int) é a id da batida
**colaborador_id** (int) é a matrícula do funcionário
**registro** (time) é a hora da batida ex: 07:30:00, 12:00:00..
**data** (date) é a data referente a batida.
**tipo** (char) é o tipo da batida entrada ou saída.

---

Exemplo:
 se um funcionário tiver as seguintes batidas:

batida_id =>1 colaborador_id=> 1 data => 01/06/2016 batida => 07:30 tipo => entrada
batida_id =>2 colaborador_id=> 1 data => 01/06/2016 batida => 12:00 tipo => saida
batida_id =>3 colaborador_id=> 1 data => 01/06/2016 batida => 13:30 tipo => entrada
batida_id =>4 colaborador_id=> 1 data => 01/06/2016 batida => 17:00 tipo => saida

a tabela teria que ficar assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consegui fazer só uma parte da tabela, nao consigo fazer a logica para mostrar as batidas na frente das datas.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
  <th>Data</th>
  <th>Dia Semana</th>
  <th>Ocorrências</th>
  </tr>  <br />

    <?php


    $diasSemana[1] = 'Segunda-feira';
    $diasSemana[2] = 'Terça-feira';
    $diasSemana[3] = 'Quarta-feira';
    $diasSemana[4] = 'Quinta-feira';
    $diasSemana[5] = 'Sexta-feira';
    $diasSemana[6] = 'Sábado';
    $diasSemana[7] = 'Domingo';


    for($dias = 1; $dias <= date('t',strtotime('2016-06')); $dias++)

    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>".$dias."</th>" . "<th>".$diasSemana[date('N', strtotime("2016-06-$dias"))] ."</th>" . "<th>";


        }


   echo "</tr>";

?>    
             </table>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Escrever AJUDA, HELP, PLEASE não faz a pergunta ser mais urgente, todos veem aqui precisando de ajuda, escrever HELP e AJUDA é totalmente redundante, seja objetivo ao escrever. Entenda como uma critica construtiva. (eu já editei o titulo)

Comment: Outra coisa o "stack snippet" é obviamente usado para executar javascript, html e css, ou seja front-end, não tem porque usar stacksnippet para colocar php, c++, java, c#, isso nunca vai funcionar. Leia o Help e aprenda a usar a marcação de texto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting --- O help está ae pra essas duvidas. E por favor entenda como uma critica construtiva. (eu já removi o stack snippet)

Comment: Mano, me passa o select que está fazendo

Comment: é esse o problema, tipo como eu faço esse tipo de sql?

Comment: E já existe o banco e as tabelas?

Comment: Já existe o banco e a tabela...

Comment: Estava tentando aqui mas sem chance, não consigo trazer as marcações na frente da data

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    # valor que vem do formulario (se houver)
    $colaborador = 1;

    # todos os resultados por ordem de dia e hora (não importa a entrada e saída) de uma matricula (se for de todos, retire o WHERE)
    $resultado = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE colaborador = {$colaborador} 
    ORDER BY dia ASc, HOUR(hora) ASC";

    # se vier um array valido
    if (is_array($resultado) && count($resultado) >0)
    {
        # uma variável para armazenar as horas
        $dia_hora = array();
        foreach($resultado as $key => $value)
        {
            # agrupar dia e hora
            $dia_hora[$value['dia'][] = $value['hora'];
        }
        # construir a tabela
        echo "<table>" . PHP_EOL .
        "<tbody>";
        foreach($resultado as $key => $value)
        {
           echo "<tr>" . PHP_EOL .
                "<td>{$value['dia']</td>" . PHP_EOL;
            # aqui é a forma (que eu achei) para imprimir a entrada e saída na mesma linha e dividir as mesmas por coluna
            $dia[$value['dia'][] = $value['hora'];
            foreach($dia_hora[$value['dia']] as $dia => $hora)
            {
               # 0 (entrada)
               # 1 (saída) 
               echo "<td>{$hora[0]}</td>" . PHP_EOL .
               "<td>{$hora[1]}</td>" . PHP_EOL;
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody>" . PHP_EOL .
        "</table>";
```

Comment: William, tentei usar seu código adaptei ao meu aqui mais não está dando certo :/

Comment: # agrupar dia e hora
    $dia_hora[$value['dia']][] = $value['hora'];

fiz errado do código, faltou uma ] no final. Desculpe. Tente novamente.